# How can we get future / past datetime of Jmeter in seconds?

Tags: jmeter

I would like to get future / past date in my Jmeter. I tried timeShift but it returns **milliseconds** by default, I would like to use it in **seconds** because my system does.

I have tried many ways but can not figure it out. Can you all show me how ? Or other methods ?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAXfF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [__timeShift()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) and [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) functions combination

- with `__timeShift()` you will get the date in past/future in milliseconds since start of the [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)
- and with `__jexl3()` you can simply divide the resulting value by `1000` to get the value in seconds

Demo:

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)

Answer (score -1):

In your `timeShift` call, edit the 'time format' parameter to '/1000'. Something like `${__timeShift(/1000,,P2D,,)}` (to get a shift of 2 days in seconds).

Comment: Sorry, I have tried this but it returned `date=/1000` for the result